# Turn off notification about broken connection in putty

Tags: ssh, putty

When putty gets connection broken (whether by losing connectivity or e.g. by hibernating computer) it displays annoying message box "Network error: Software caused connection abort".

Is there some way to turn this off? I am quite capable of noticing "Putty (inactive)" text in title bar of putty window, thank you very much. I searched through all the options and can't find anything to turn this annoying message box off. Is there something in registry maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question prompted me to look through the source code for PuTTY, and in short the answer is no. (for the windows version at least, which was the one I looked at) I suppose you could edit the code and compile it if you really wanted to.

Comment: Well I have added just this (and another) capability to PuTTY: https://bitbucket.org/mrkafk/puttyabled/wiki/Home  :-)